# Cannot minimize main window in Thunderbird 40.0 on Windows 10

Tags: thunderbird, windows-10

Since upgrading to Windows 10, the top bar minimize/maximize/close buttons on the main window do not work in version 40.0 beta channel. Other Thunderbird windows (Write mail, options, etc) work fine, and all my windows in other applications work fine.

It previously worked fine in Windows 7 before upgrading. I can minimize by clicking the icon in the Windows Task bar, but the not by clicking the buttons in the top bar.

Is this a known issue? On another machine also upgraded to Windows 10 but running the release channel version 38.1.0 it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got 41.0 beta channel and it does NOT have the problem, so they must have fixed the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. The app must be closed by File -> Exit. All three buttons work the same as the Fullscreen/Window button (middle one). You can Right Click the buttons and click Minimise or Maximise as a workaround. Clearly a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in Thunderbird for a while. I restarted in safe mode (Hamburger menu>Help>Restart with Add-ons disabled...), then closed Thunderbird and opened it again and the buttons started working again.